# Clever Collision Counting

Tags: physics

A mass of 1,000,000kg is sliding in from the right on a friction-free, level surface.

It has a perfectly elastic collision (**collision 1**) with a stationary 1kg mass.

To the left of the 1kg mass is a wall and the 1kg mass bounces off the wall with perfect elasticity (**collision 2**).

It bounces back towards the 1,000,000kg mass where it collides again (**collision 3**) and heads back towards the wall.

This goes on, each time bleeding a little of the 1,000,000kg mass's speed, eventually turning it around until both masses are heading to the right, the 1,000,000kg mass heading slightly faster than the 1kg mass, and they will never collide again.

> How many collisions take place?

Comment: Ah, I remembered watching this problem in Youtube, and the answer is surprising  :)

Comment: @athin, it's very cool. I will link the video if the solver doesn't. But if you don't know the video, it's worth tackling the problem because it's got a very neat solution

Comment: I too have seen the video and so consider myself disqualified from answering. (I don't remember off the top of my head how it worked, but I remember the sort of answer it got and I'm sure that if I try to prove it I will be reconstructing more than I am creating.)

Comment: Well, I've reconstructed an answer; it might even be right. It's probably the same approach as in the video but my memory is terrible :-). Anyway, seems like it would be unfair to post it; I'll leave it for someone else to work out who hasn't seen it before.

Comment: I am surprised that the speed of the two masses does not impact the computation. It is an issue of momentum - the change of momentum for the 1,000,000, each collision, is twice the momentum of the small mass.

Comment: It assumes non-relativistic speeds, I suppose! But otherwise everything just scales. It is a little surprising.

Comment: I have not seen this before (or searched for a video), but as well as what @Moti says I notice that rot13(gur qvfgnapr sebz gur fznyy znff gb gur jnyy vf nyfb abg fgngrq naq fb (yvxr fbzr bgure ceboyrzf) fcrrq naq qvfgnapr qvny bhg bs gur zngu).

Comment: What Weather says: the distance from the small mass to the wall is also not stated and so (like some other problems) speed and distance dial out of the math

Comment: @Bass sorry to hear that. V frustrating!

Comment: The other part of what @Moti [said](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93778/clever-collision-counting#comment268996_93778) cannot be true because rot13(gur fznyyre znff vavgvnyyl unf mreb zbzraghz).

Comment: @Bass that sucks big time :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do graphs to this puzzle.
(Spoiler alert: I spoiler tagged the bare minimum to keep this even halfway readable)

First we need to figure out what to plot. Since the game is "elastic collisions", plotting the conservation laws for momentum and kinetic energy is probably a good idea.

$$m_Bv_B + m_Sv_S = constant$$ 
$$m_Bv_B^2 + m_Sv_S^2 = constant$$
where the "m"s are masses, "v"s are velocities, and the subscript B and S mean the "big object" and the "small object" respectively.

(If you wonder where the "$\frac{1}{2}$"s from the conservation of kinetic energy disappeared, I dropped them for convenience: two times a constant is still a constant, just some other one.)

Plotting these with the velocities as the coordinate axes should give us a straight line for the first one, and some second order curve for the latter.

To plot the latter law, let's divide everything by $m_Bm_S$, and then choose the units so that the right side becomes one:

$$ \frac{v_B^2}{m_S} + \frac{v_S^2}{m_B}=1 $$

This we instantly recognise as a formula for an ellipse with the square roots of the masses as the semi-axes.

So let's go ahead and plot them. Let's use 9kg as the bigger mass to make the plot readable. (Sorry about the axis labels, they're from an earlier attempt that the PSE captcha checker ate. Please mentally substitute B for 1 and S for 2.)

[image]

It's important to notice that any line parallel with the red one will conserve momentum, and that our two speeds can never be anywhere else than on the blue ellipse.

In the initial state, we are at the top of the ellipse (all speed on the big mass).
Any collision between the masses must conserve momentum, so we move in the direction of the red line until we hit another point on the ellipse.

When the smaller mass hits the wall, its speed is reversed while the big mass's speed stays unaffected. So we can plot the consecutive states on the graph like this:

[image]

To reiterate, the red transitions represent the two masses colliding, the green ones represent the smaller mass hitting the wall.

Here we had a mass ratio of 9:1 and by my freehand graphing, we got 9 collisions. Coincidence? Most likely. But let's see..

Ellipses are hard. Let's scale the horizontal axis down by the square root of the weight ratio which is 3 in this case:

[image]

As you can probably see, I literally told gimp to scale the image from earlier.

This triples the slope of the "conservation of momentum" lines, and, more importantly, turns the blue "conservation of kinetic energy" curve into a unit circle. Now THAT's progress.

The midpoint of the circle arc spanned by the red line from "start" to "1" looks important. If we draw a line through it and the circle's center, we get a line that's perpendicular to all the red lines:

[image]

I've used theta (θ) to mark the angle that the important line makes with the vertical, since now we can find all the other collision points as multiples of θ: The momentum-conserving red lines are all perpendicular to the important line, so a collision between the two masses mirrors the state to the other side of the important line, and a collision between the smaller mass and the wall just negates the angle.

```
Collision  angle from vertical, in theta units
    1          2
    2         -2
    3          4
    4         -4
    5          6
    6         -6
```

And there's the pattern we need to solve the puzzle. Calculating how many thetas we need to traverse the required half circle will directly tell us the number of collisions needed.

Let's first calculate the accurate value for the 9:1 weight ratio case. We know that the slope of the red lines is $-\frac{1}{\sqrt9}$, and that we can also find theta as its angle from the horizontal:

$$ \theta = -arctan(-\frac{1}{\sqrt9})$$

and so the required number of bounces is

$$\frac{\pi}{\theta} = \frac{\pi}{-arctan(-\frac{1}{\sqrt9})} \approx 9.8 $$

which quite encouragingly agrees with the drawing from earlier.

Finally, replacing the "9" in the above formula with 1,000,000, we get

> $$ \textbf{Number of collisions} = \frac{\pi}{-arctan(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1,000,000}})} \approx \mathbf{3141} $$

and even more finally, applying a small angle approximation of $arctan(\theta) \approx \theta$, a general result would be

> $$\text{Number of collisions} \approx \pi\sqrt{\frac{m_B}{m_S}}$$

which applies as long as the big mass is much larger than the small one.

I've invested way more time to this puzzle than intended, so instead of triple checking, I'm going to have to let you guys point out all my mistakes :-)

Comment: Way to get back on the horse! And fantastic answer. Only small thing is that the number of collisions is the lower floor of your expression. +1 now and tick to follow. I want to see if any other methods occur to people to get this surprising answer.

Comment: @DrXorile ah, good point. Since I cannot just now find the brain power to figure out the details of the final bounce, I'm afraid I'll have to go with the approx instead of the floor :-) I too am really looking forward to seeing if there's a less circuitous route to the answer than the one I took. (In reality (not entirely depicted above), I took long forays into centre-of-mass coordinate systems and geometrical sums before finding this approach, so I'm pretty sure any other way has got to be more straightforward than mine..)

Comment: Your solution is reasonably straight forward (once you've found it!). You change from physics to geometry and solve the geometry. There may be an easier way to see the geometry. The small angle approximation of $\tan x\approx x$ helps, and the idea that the subtended angle is half the angle to the centre of the circle.